# what is the correct way to use launch_template in aws_eks_node_group block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

```
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
  node_group_name = "cluster-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks-nodegroup.arn
  subnet_ids      = [aws_subnet.public.id, aws_subnet.public2.id]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size = 6
    min_size = 1
  }

  launch_template = {
    id   = aws_launch_template.cluster.id
    version = $Latest 
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
  ]
```

I receive the fallowing error

- on main.tf line 137, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "cluster-group":
  137:   launch_template = {

An argument named "launch_template" is not expected here.*

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since [launch_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#launch_template-configuration-block) is a block, not a map, I would say that you shouldn't use equal sign in its definition:

```
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.cluster.id
    version = $Latest 
  }
```